# How to go back to the origin of the page before log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Rails 6 and Devise.

In Case A, here's the flow, which is correct:

1. User logs in
2. Views Shops index page (`/shops`)
3. Clicks Add New Shop (`/shops/new`)
4. Views Shop New page (`/shops/new`) with a back link (`<link_to "Back", :back...>`), with the back link correctly points to Shops index
5. Clicks Back
6. Goes back to Shops index page (`/shops`)

In Case B, here's the flow, which is a problem:

1. User is not logged in
2. Views Shops index page (`/shops`)
3. Clicks Add New Shop (`/shops/new`)
4. User is redirected to login page
5. User logs in
6. Views Shop New page (`/shops/new`) with a back link (`<link_to "Back", :back...>`), with the back link points back to itself (`/shops/new`)
7. Clicks Back
8. Views Shop New page (`/shops/new`) again

In Case B, how to correctly points the back link back to Shops index page?

Comment: I would just avoid `link_to 'Back', :back` since there are so many pitfalls. Instead just link to index page.

Comment: Not really sure why you are using `:back` in there.  Is it always suppose to go back to the index page?  If so I would just put that in there, using `:back` makes me think that it doesn't though, are users coming to this page from different areas, and not always going back to the index page?

Comment: Users might come in from other places, e.g. From User Profile menu -> Add New Shop.

Comment: Try link_to_function "Back", "history.back()"